# No service dependencies found in Jaeger UI

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, minikube, jaeger

I am new to jaeger and I am facing issues with finding the services list in the jaeger UI.

Below are the .yaml configurations I prepared to run jaeger with my spring boot app on Kubernetes using minikube locally.

`kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/production-elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml --namespace=kube-system`

`kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/master/jaeger-production-template.yml --namespace=kube-system`

Created deployment for my spring boot app and jaeger agent to run on the same container

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: tax-app-deployment
spec:
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: tax-app
          version: latest
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: tax-app
          name: tax-app
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        - image: jaegertracing/jaeger-agent
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: jaeger-agent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5775
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 5778
          - containerPort: 6831
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 6832
            protocol: UDP
          command:
          - "/go/bin/agent-linux"
          - "--collector.host-port=jaeger-collector.jaeger-infra.svc:14267"
```

And the spring boot app service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tax
  labels:
    app: tax-app
    jaeger-infra: tax-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tax-port
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    jaeger-infra: jaeger-tax
```

I am getting

> No service dependencies found

Comment: When do you get this "I am getting No service dependencies found" error? Which command you use that creates this error?

Comment: I am getting it when I am loading the jaeger ui and after going to dependencies tab

Comment: does your upstream service implement jaeger?

Answer (score 2):

Service graph data must be generated in Jaeger. Currently it's possible with via a Spark job here: https://github.com/jaegertracing/spark-dependencies